# Maximum of $\cos (2k\pi \alpha) $

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have confusing with small question that:

Given $ \alpha$ is an irrational number. So, does there exist a constant $c  < 1$ such that

$\cos (2k\pi\alpha) \leq c$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

One can show that if $\alpha$ is irrational, then the set $\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle (in fact, Weyl proved that this set is equidistributed). Since $\cos(2\pi k\alpha)=\Re e^{2\pi ik\alpha}$, it follows that $\{\cos(2\pi k\alpha)\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. So the answer is no.